# Derivative at point but point itself converges

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Say, that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=1$ anď $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-1}{x} = 1$ then we get $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)=1$

Is this an obvious conclusion?

I think there is one omitted thing for this approach.

$$\lim_{x\to 0, \tau\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(\tau)}{x-\tau} = \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$$

Am I right? I don't know how to prove this since I haven't learned higher math but naive definition of derivative with graph (slope of tangent line)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're partially right. If we assume that $f$ is continuous at $0$, that is $f(0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 1$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x} = 1$ means only that $f'(0)=1$, but it doesn't have to mean that $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, which would imply $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x) = 1$.

However, if $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$, then you still have
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \Big(\lim_{\tau\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(\tau)}{x-\tau}\Big) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(0)$$

What you want is the limit
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \Big(\lim_{\tau\rightarrow x} \frac{f(x)-f(\tau)}{x-\tau}\Big) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x)$$

ADDENDUM: An example.

Function $$f(x)=1+x+x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$$ satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-1}{x} = 1$, but limits $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \big(1+2x\sin\frac{1}{x} - \cos\frac{1}{x}\big) $$
and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0, \tau\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(\tau)}{x-\tau} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0, \tau\rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\tau + x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} - \tau^2\sin\frac{1}{\tau}}{x-\tau}$$
don't exist. To see that the last limit doesn't exist, consider the sequence $(x_n,\tau_n) = (\frac{1}{(n+\frac12)\pi},\frac{1}{n\pi})$.

Comment: Oh, yea thanks, but i thought f being discontinuous at 0 woudln't help tho.

Comment: It is possible that $f(0)=1$, $f'(0)=1$, $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$, but $f'(x)$ is not continuous and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f;(x)$ doesn't exist. An example of such function is $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$. You can calculate
$$ f'(0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)\frac{x + x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}=1$$
but for $x\neq 0$ you have
$$ f'(x) = 1 +2x\sin\frac{1}{x} - \cos\frac{1}{x}$$ which doesn't have a limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$.

Comment: Doesn't both x and k conveging to 0 implies x->t? Since x-t converges to 0?

Comment: The very first deduction is true **only** if we assume $\;f(0)=1\;$ , and this is given nowhere. Even $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=1\;$ isn't enough.

Comment: Don) Okay, but im given f(0)=1/2 not 1

Comment: @DonAntonio You're right. If $f(x)$ isn't continuous at $0$, then $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @SolvablePotato Read Adam's last comment: in that case there is no $\;f'(0)\;$ at all

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry i think existance of f'(0) has no role here, i now think im confusing with derivative and differentiation. Could you correctly list me which of these are right? 1. f(x) is differentiable at 0/ 2.lim of derivative exists at 0/ 3. derivative exists at 0

Comment: I think 1,2 is true while 3 is false right?

Comment: @SolvablePotato It'd be interesting to read your definitions, but in fact differential and derivative *in one varible* are basically and exactly the very same thing...

Comment: @DonAntonio What you are mentioning and causing to confuse me is : existance of f'(0). the  exercise says f(0)=1/2, f not differentiable at 0. So i seek to find limit of f'(x) at 0 is it nonsense? And actual purpose of exercise isnt to evaluate f'(0) what im doing is only part of it and it is first thing necessary to do

Comment: @SolvablePotato It's true that even if $f'(0)$ doesn't exist, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x)$ may still exist. But the assumptions you've made in your question are not enough to guarantee that it does exist.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Okay, i'll adopt your answer i now get some points of your view now. I'll read more books and try to think in more strict and fundamental way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implicitly assumes that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood $I$ of $0$ except possibly at $0$ (if it were not so then it would not make sense to talk of limit of $f'(x) $).

Let $g$ be another function defined in the same neighborhood $I$ of $0$ such that $g(x) =f(x), x\neq 0$ and $g(0)=1$. Then $g$ is continuous in its domain $I$ and further $g$ is differentiable in $I$ with $g'(x) =f'(x), x\neq 0,g'(0)=1$.

With these conditions we can't conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g'(x)$ exists. However by mean value theorem one can show that if this limit exists then it must equal $g'(0)=1$.